# Strange output writing to file in C

Tags: c, file, file-io

I am trying to append a string to a text file, but I am getting odd characters.
If I try to print out my result to the console, output is regular.
This is what i see as the output in vim. If I look at it in gedit I get strange boxes.

Output File:

```
  A^CA^BB^A
  A^CB^BA^A
  B^CA^BA^A
```

Expected Output:

```
AAB
ABA
BAA
```

My function should write out the permutations with no duplicates into a text file.

Code For Function:

```
void RecursivePermute (char *prefix, char *rest, int *ptr)
{
    char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char *new_prefix = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char *rest_left = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char *rest_right = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char *new_rest = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    char rest_char;
    int idx = 0;
    int first_occurance = 0;
    int i;
    FILE *file;
    strcpy(temp, rest);
    if (*rest == '\0')
    {
        *ptr += 1;
        printf("Permutation %d: %s\n", *ptr, prefix);
        file = fopen("permutations.txt", "a");
        fprintf(file,"%s\n",prefix);
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        size_t rest_size = strlen(rest);
        while (*rest != '\0')
        {

            first_occurance = (strchr(temp, *rest) - temp - idx);
            if (first_occurance == 0)
            {
                rest_char = *rest;
                rest_left = strncpy(rest_left, rest-idx, idx);
                rest_right = strncpy(rest_right, rest+1, rest_size-1);
                sprintf(new_rest, "%s%s", rest_left, rest_right);
                sprintf(new_prefix,"%s%s", prefix, &rest_char);
                RecursivePermute( new_prefix, new_rest, ptr);
            }
            rest++;
            idx ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you also showed the call to the function, showing the arguments you are passing that give the result you show.

Comment: @steveha I am calling the function with RecursivePermute("", letters, &count); //Where count=0; and letters[]="AAB";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is that your printf format specifier for &rest_char is wrong. &rest_char can't be interpreted as a string because it is not null-terminated. If you want to print out a character use %c. Your line should look like this:

```
sprintf(new_prefix,"%s%c", prefix, rest_char);
```

Also you might want to look and see how you are allocating strings. By specifying a size of sizeof(char *) it will only create a memory allocation the size of a pointer. If the string in rest is greater than that it will cause a buffer overrun when you do the strcpy.

Comment: yes that fixed the problem I was having. I will also try to figure out the problems I'm having with sizeof(char *) and strcpy.

Comment: If you know your strings won't ever exceed a certain length just declare them as an array, char temp[120], and then use strncpy(temp, rest, 120);

Comment: @NathanMoinvaziri, no `strncpy` is dangerous when used like that. One must always care to have space for an extra null character. One safe way to use it would be to do `strncpy(temp, rest, 119); temp[119] = '\0';`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `malloc(sizeof(char *))`, you are allocating a buffer of four bytes (or eight bytes if you are compiling for 64-bit).  This almost certainly isn't what you want.

Then, you use `strcpy()` which doesn't check length.  I almost never even use `strcpy()` anymore.

You also use `strncpy()`, which does check length, but I kind of hate it because it doesn't guarantee that the string will be properly null-terminated; if you copy a string that is length 4 or longer, and the buffer can hold only 4 characters, there is no null.

So, I haven't run your program under a debugger, but when you put all these problems together I am not suprised your program is misbehaving.

Comment: And the memory he allocates with `malloc` is leaked. This code is just... a disaster

Comment: @stevenha Thank you for your input I very much appreciate it. Your right I guess I should be using sizeof(char) instead. I will also look into strncpy(). At=>Nik B can you explain to me what you mean when you say my malloc allocation is leaked?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1.  Unless your strings are length 1, you don't want this.  If the longest string you could ever have would be 120 characters, you might try `malloc(121)` (don't forget you need to allocate space for every character plus the terminating ASCII 0 "null" character).  What he means about the allocation being leaked: you allocate memory with `malloc()` but you never call `free()` on the memory.  For a toy program like this, that's okay, because the memory is returned when the program ends.  But it's not a bad idea to get in the habit of calling `free()` when you are done with mem.